# Android Firebase Authentication Not Working On Release APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I implemented Firebase authentication and it works when app is installed from Android Studio but not from exported release apk (or from Google Playstore).

I did the following:

- Copied the app SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from Google Play Store - Release managemet - App signing.
- On Firebase console under Project settings - My App I Added Fingerprint and pasted the SHA-1 characters from Google Playstore Console.
- Now I have 2 SHA-1 (Debug and Release) under Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints
- I downloaded the google-services.json and added it to the root of my /app directory and re-generated signed apk.
- The `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` calls `public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e)` with the following exception returned:

  ```
  This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console.
  ```

I even generated the SHA-1 from command line using release keystore and the same SHA-1 from Google Playstore is generated.

Also, why are developers hiding their SHA-1 keys in screenshots?

Comment: "why are developers hiding their SHA-1 keys in screenshots?" : because if i have access to your key i can request and modify your data from your firebase db

Answer (score 2):

Ok this is strange but it worked nontheless:

I removed all SHA-1 keys from Firebase and added the Google Playstore SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from `Upload certificate` instead of `App signing certificate`

Comment: I added the `Upload certificate` key to firebase but is not working anyway... When I install the `.apk` manually everything is fine, but when I install it form `Google play` the authentication doesn't work. Does someone had the same problem and solved it?

Comment: You can try adding SHA1 to Firebase certificates also, It is presented in the Internal app sharing, You can find in       Google Play console -> Release -> Setup -> Internal app sharing, scroll to the bottom of the screen you will find it there.